# How do I set custom user claims upon registration in PHP Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set a role on users upon registration on my PHP Firebase database but I only ever see instructions on how to do it *after* registration.

Is it actually impossible? If not then how do I do it? I've tried this

```
if(isset($_POST['register_btn']))
{
    $fullname = $_POST['full_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $role = $_POST['role_as'];

    $userProperties = [
        'email' => $email,
        'emailVerified' => false,
        'phoneNumber' => '+63'.$phone,
        'password' => $password,   
        'displayName' => $fullname,
        'role_as' =>$role,
    ];

    if($role == "registrar")
    {
        $createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);

        if($createdUser)
        {
            $auth->setCustomUserClaims($key, ['registrar' => true]);
            $_SESSION['status'] = "User created successfully.";
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        }
    
    
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "User creation failed.";
            header('Location: register.php');
            exit();
    }
   
    }
}
```

but it clearly didn't work. I'm seeing that I am missing the $key, which is supposed to be the ID of the user but as it's not registered yet, there is none. How would I do this?

Comment: Presumably, `$createdUser` would contain the info you need?

Answer (score 2):

As ADyson commented, the call to `createUser` returns a `UserRecord` that contains a `$uid` property.

Also see:

- the [definition of `UserRecord`](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/7.x/src/Firebase/Auth/UserRecord.php) in the library code